# Embedding html in pentaho report designer

Tags: html, embed, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I would like to generate a pdf report from a page in my web app.
I'm considering using pentaho report designer for our reports in general.

Is it possible to "paste"/embed html code directly into the report?

I was unable to do that\ find documentation\example of this ability.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definately do this, i've rendered html stored in fields.
Err, now the problem is, at this moment i can't remember exactly how. Look carefully through the properties on the field, one of those will be one that allows you to set the content type as "rich text".

IIRC it supported a basic set of html, wont handle anything too fancy!

this was a great feature for us, as we had html stored in the db, so we rendered the html direct, very nice feature!  before we had this feature we had to strip the tags from the html and display it as text - nasty!